# Why doe this equal -(negative) 49 ? Please explain

Tags: inequality

I am just wondering why the answer to this problem -22 - w ≥27 is a -(minus or negative) 49?
It does not make sense to me why it would be a negative and not just 49?

Comment: $$-22-49=-71<0<27\qquad;\qquad-22-(-49)=-22+49=49-22=27\ge27.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$-22-w\ge27\iff -w\ge 49\iff w\le-49$$

When you multiply both sides of the inequality by a negative number, the inequality sign reverses. More generally:

$$a\le b\iff -a\ge -b$$

For example: $1\le 2 \iff -1\ge-2$

Answer (score 0):

Just try it:
starting with -49 we get:
$$
-22 - (-49) \geq 27 
$$
Minus times minus is plus:
$$
-22 + 49 \geq 27 \\
27 \geq 27 
$$
so -49 seems to be ONE of MANY different solutions for w. On the contrary, trying 49 gives:
$$
-22 - 49 \geq 27 \\
-71 \geq 27
$$
which is obviously not true.